# Есть шестнадцатеричные цветные коды RGB которые находятся в многомерном массиве.Как определить преобладающий цвет в подмассивах

Tags: python-3.x, list, hex

> Учитывая массив с 3 вложенными, каждый из которых содержит шестнадцатеричные цветные коды, свободно определяющие красные,
> зеленые и синие цвета на основе их преобладающего значения байта,
> верните строку описание того, какой из трех цветов содержит каждый массив.

> Ввод - это массив, который содержит 3 вложенных.Эти вложенные содержат строки, представляющие цвета в
> формате RGB, каждая строка будет содержать один преобладающий цветовой канал, который более насыщен,
> чем два других.Среди всех строк во вложенных массивах только 2 цветных канала появятся как преобладающие
> тот, который кажется чаще, является «основным», а тот, который кажется реже, «вспомогательный».
> Задача состоит в том, чтобы определить основные и незначительные цвета внутри каждого подмассива и вернуть
> их в следующем формате: {major1}+{minor1}, {major2}+{minor2}, {major3}+{minor3}

**Вот мой код:**

```
def get_colors(col_arr):
    lst = []
    # Разбиваем в каждом подмассиве 16-ричный код по - первые 2-а символа - red, 2-ые - green,
    #  3-и blue, и приводим их к int
    # red(255, 0, 0)  green(0, 255, 0)  blue(0, 0, 255)
    for i in range(len(col_arr)):
        ls = []
        for j in range(len(col_arr[i])):
            l = []
            for k in range(0, len(col_arr[i][j]), 2):
                l.append(int(col_arr[i][j][k:k + 2], 16))
            ls.append(l)
        lst.append(ls)
    print(lst)
    print()
    ll = []
    # Суммируем все значения десятичные для red, green, blue для каждого подмассива
    for el in lst:
        ans = list(zip(*el))
        ll.append(ans)
    print(ll)
    print()
    tt = []
    # Суммируем десятичные значения каждого цвета в подмассивах
    for el in ll:
        l = []
        for item in el:
            l.append(sum(item))
        tt.append(l)
    # Получаем суммированные десятичные значения для каждого цвета в каждом подмассиве
    print(tt) 

col_arr = [ [ "FF0000", "8DC4DE", "87CEFA", "4169E1", "0000FF" ],
    [ "FF0000", "191970", "00008B" ],
    [ "CD5C5C", "F08080", "0000FF" ] ]
# Ответ --- "Blue+Red,Blue+Red,Red+Blue" для 1, 2, 3 подмассивов
```

Вот все print()

```
# [[[255, 0, 0], [141, 196, 222], [135, 206, 250], [65, 105, 225], [0, 0, 255]], [[255, 0, 0], [25, # 25, 112], [0, 0, 139]], [[205, 92, 92], [240, 128, 128], [0, 0, 255]]]

# [[(255, 141, 135, 65, 0), (0, 196, 206, 105, 0), (0, 222, 250, 225, 255)], [(255, 25, 0), (0, 25, # 0), (0, 112, 139)], [(205, 240, 0), (92, 128, 0), (92, 128, 255)]]

# [[596, 507, 952], [280, 25, 251], [445, 220, 475]]
#  red  green blue  red green blue   red  green blue
# "Blue+Red"         "Blue+Red"     "Red+Blue"
```

У меня не получается правильное сравнение по десятичным значениям
Подскажите как сравнить правильно???

> Example: input = [ ["FFA07A", "FA8072", "8DC4DE"], ["7FFF00", "ADFF2F", "FF0000", "00FF7F", "00FF7F"], ["ADD8E6", "6B8E23", "9ACD32", "32CD32", "00FF00"] ] result = "Red+Blue,Green+Red,Green+Blue" Explanation: first subarray's predominant colors: Red, Red, Blue (Red is major, Blue is minor) second subarray's predominant colors: Green, Green, Red, Green, Green (Green is major, Red is minor) third subarray's predominant colors: Blue, Green, Green, Green, Green (Green is major, Blue is minor)

Задание вот по ссылке https://www.codewars.com/kata/597a660f59873cc353000061/train/python

Comment: А что с чем вы хотите сравнить собственно и какой результат получить?

Comment: Kromster Сравнить сумму (десятичное значение ) для red с green сравним и сравним с blue максимальная сумма будет преобладающим цветом в подмассиве.Второй максимум будет "вспомогательным" цветом  --- в описании написано: Среди всех строк во вложенных массивах только 2 цветных канала появятся как преобладающие тот, который кажется чаще, является «основным», а тот, который кажется реже, «вспомогательный» --- вот я сравнивал [[596, 507, 952], [280, 25, 251], [445, 220, 475]]  red->596---вспомогательный  основной blue->952  --- в первом подмассиве -ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ "Blue+Red" .В других подмассивах нет

Comment: Вот вы алгоритм описали (хотя он странный, обычно по HSV/HSL сравнивают оттенок, но не суть важно). В чем вопрос, в чем затруднения с реализацией конкретно? По шагам в отладчике проходили, все значения выводятся как вы ожидаете? И как именно получаемый результат отличается от ожидаемого?

Comment: Поясняю на примере 2-ого подмассива [ "FF0000", "191970", "00008B" ]Разбиваем в  подмассиве 16-ричный код  - первые 2-а символа - red, 2-ые - green, 3-и blue, и приводим их к int  Получаем вот такой массив с десятичными значениями [[255, 0, 0], [25, # 25, 112], [0, 0, 139]] Далее складываю  по red - по green  по blue (lдесятичные значения) Получается вот такой массив [280, 25, 251] --- и вот сравниваю red -> 280 он максимальный, blue->251 - второй максимум. Мой ответ получается "Red+Blue" ----> но в задании ответ "Blue+Red"  --- но ведь 280 > 251. Вот тут и вся проблема в сравнение цвета

Comment: Получается у меня красный цвет имеет значение 280 и он должен быть записан в строку ответа первым он преобладающий . Далее посмотри - правда без перевода - я может плохо пояснил тогда вот тут может понятнее

Comment: Example:

input = [
  ["FFA07A", "FA8072", "8DC4DE"],
  ["7FFF00", "ADFF2F", "FF0000", "00FF7F", "00FF7F"],
  ["ADD8E6", "6B8E23", "9ACD32", "32CD32", "00FF00"]
]

result = "Red+Blue,Green+Red,Green+Blue"

Explanation:

    first subarray's predominant colors: Red, Red, Blue (Red is major, Blue is minor)
    second subarray's predominant colors: Green, Green, Red, Green, Green (Green is major, Red is minor)
    third subarray's predominant colors: Blue, Green, Green, Green, Green (Green is major, Blue is minor)

Comment: Все уточнения и правки вносите прямо в тело вопроса - кнопка "править".